# fill a matrix with an existing data

Tags: python

I want to construct a matrix with the dimension (40,20). 40 in x and 20 in y.
I want to fill the matrix with some existing data obtained from reading a file using h5py library.
What I code is :

```
matrix = numpy.zeros([40,20])
for j in range (20):
    for i in range (20):
        matrix[j,i] = numpy.array(readFile['phi'])[0,0,j,i]
print(matrix)
```

readFile is just `readFile = h5py('File','r')` this is not an issue, my code it works in filling the matrix by the correct value that I want. So I obtained the first 20 lines and  the rest of the other 20 lines are equal to zero. (as the matrix is 40 lines in dimensions, 20 columns)
My issue here, and what I want, is instead of getting values for the 20 first lines and zeros from lines 21 to 40, I want to fill my matrix by zeros from line 1 to 20 and then values from 21 to 40.
Do you have any ideas on how I can get this directly without any reshaping. I guess that I need to modify the line `from i in range (20)`? and specify that my i concerns line 21 to 40 ???
Thank you

When I tried this:

```py
matrix = numpy.zeros([40,20])
for j in range (1:20):
    for i in range (20):
        matrix[j,i] = numpy.array(readFile['phi'])[0,0,j,i]
print(matrix)
```

It turns the first line to zeros, however the second line still have the same values. and what was. before in the first line was just missed.  What I was expecting with `for j in range (1:20)` is to bring to first line to zeros and replace the values of the second line with the one of the first line.

Comment: In your `for` loop, is `matrix` supposed to be `matrix[i,j]`?

Comment: yes, It is a mistake I done matrix[i,j] = numpy..... instead

Comment: I corrected it in the text, and I add a test that I tried

Comment: So `numpy.array(readFile['phi'])[0,0,j,i]` should correspond to `matrix[j+20,i]`? Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi, @Sara! Does `for j in range(20,40)` work for you?

Comment: BTW, instead of re-executing `numpy.array(readFile['phi'])` at every iteration of the `for` loop, I'd recommend adding the statement `phi = numpy.array(readFile['phi'])` before your loops, and replace `numpy.array(readFile['phi'])[0,0,j,i]` with `phi[0,0,j,i]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do. First, I'd read in `numpy.array(readFile['phi'])` into a variable, like this:

```py
phi = numpy.array(readFile['phi'])
```

Next, I notice that you want the "bottom half" of `matrix`, i.e. `matrix[20:40,:]`, set to the values in the 20x20 subarray at `phi[0,0]`. Well, in NumPy, you can express that equality directly, without any `for` loops, like this:

```py
matrix[20:40, :] = phi[0,0]
```

If you want to be more explicit, you can instead write

```py
matrix[20:40, :] = phi[0,0,:,:]
```

Either way should work.

I'd recommend getting more familiar with how NumPy does array slicing. See here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer:

What works is:

```
    N = 20
    matrix = numpy.zeros([2*N,N])
    for j1 in range(N):
        for i1 in range (0*N,1*N):
            matrix [i1,j1] = numpy.array(readPlotFile['phi'])[0,0,i1-1*N,j1]
```